# Beautiful soup ignore multiple spaces out of tags

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

when I use BeautifulSoup to get the text from html, I find it will ignore multiple spaces. For the example below, there are 2 spaces between `</seg>` and `<seg>`, but output only have one space, and whatever how many spaces, it'll sill output one space.

```
import bs4

text = "<line><seg>aaa</seg>  <seg>bbb</seg></line>"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
print(soup.text)
print(soup.find_all(text=True))
```

output is:

```
aaa bbb
['aaa', ' ', 'bbb']
```

but what I really want is:

```
aaa  bbb
['aaa', '  ', 'bbb']
```

Any ideas?

or

if there is an equivalent way in javascript? to get text but ignore multiple spaces outside of tag

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behaviour for html parsers.

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace

To quote some relevant parts:

[HTML largely ignores whitespace?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace#html_largely_ignores_whitespace)

> In the case of HTML, whitespace is largely ignored — whitespace in
> between words is treated as a single character, and whitespace at the
> start and end of elements and outside elements is ignored.
>
> Creating space around and inside elements is the job of CSS.

[What does happen to whitespace?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace#what_does_happen_to_whitespace)

> They don't just disappear, however.
>
> Any whitespace characters that are outside of HTML elements in the
> original document are represented in the DOM. This is needed
> internally so that the editor can preserve formatting of documents.
> This means that:
>
> There will be some text nodes that contain only whitespace, and Some
> text nodes will have whitespace at the beginning or end.

[How does CSS process whitespace?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace#how_does_css_process_whitespace)

> Most whitespace characters are ignored, not all of them are.....There
> are rules in the browser engine that decide which whitespace
> characters are useful and which aren’t — these are specified at least
> in part in [CSS Text Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3), and especially the parts
> about the [CSS white-space property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-property) and [whitespace processing
> details](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-processing).